# Using the python C API, is it possible to shrink a PyUnicode object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

I can't easily find out the exact size of the string I will produce. I only know the upper bound which should be within 1-2 characters of the final size. How do I shrink the string after filling it?

Comment: You don't. In C you could use realloc, but python does not expose memory micro management routines. The real question is, why would you care about a few bytes anyway?

Comment: Also python does some interning for small strings, so what you want to do might actually use *more* memory.

Comment: @Claris 'asdf' != 'asdf\0\0'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

1. If you are trying to remove characters from your string use the .strip() method.
2. If you want the byte count of the string compared to the character count you need to change the encoding.
3. If you are just trying to remove the \0 character use the .replace() method.

Comment: I know that I will make at most 1005 ASCII characters. I allocate a 1005-character ASCII string. I fill 1003 characters. How do I make the string 1003 characters long without reallocating?